# how to create server in google cloud through google cloud api

Tags: php, api, google-cloud-platform

hi I want to create a server in google cloud  with below options

[image]

from my php web page so can anyone tell me the best guide or tutorials that guide me step by step

Comment: Start with the documentation and write some code. If you have a software/programming problem, come back with a specific question. https://cloud.google.com/php

Comment: You will find the step-by-step guide [here](https://cloud.google.com/php/tutorials/getting-started-on-compute-engine) to run an instance on GCP with PHP. If you meant something else then let me know.